# PHP sockets - what do I need to work with them?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sockets

Only yesterday, I was asking a friend of mine how he would go about emulating direct communication channels between two clients through a web server, for the purpose of creating a chat application, but by using solely PHP/MySQL/JavaScript.

He told me that the best way to do this was by the use of SOCKETS, a term I had only heard of until then. This morning I started looking into it for the purpose of creating my chat application, but I'm quickly starting to believe that it's not as easy as I'd hoped.

So my question is this:  if I don't have access to my own server (I have a domain hosted on a shared server that I also use for testing purposes), can I still use sockets to achieve my goal? If so, how exactly? (Please understand that I am completely new to the idea)
If not, what other way is there to accomplish the communication channels?
My only idea so far is to simply send periodic requests (AJAX) to the web server the application would be stored on and request any new messages, if any. But this does not seem very feasible.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what your friend is trying to get to is implementing Comet for your chat site.

Assuming he's getting you to use PHP sockets to act as a daemon, I highly doubt a shared hosting provider will let you do it.

You could try hanging the PHP script until there's data available. However, this will quickly consume resources on a CGI-based server since the PHP server can't tell if the client is still connected. I know this from experience.

For these kind of things, I highly recommend you get a dedicated server or VPS and write your backend in something like [socket.io](http://socket.io/) which automagically handles all your communication problems on both the client and server side. PHP, MYSQL and servers that fork to serve requests are usually the worst case scenarios for implementing Comet since they incur quite a bit of overhead and aren't scalable.

If you can't afford to run your own Comet server, then polling may be your only option. This will be the most resource intensive and least responsive.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation.  I too have been a bit fuzzy on this concept, and your confirmation of needed a VPS or dedicated has confirmed my suspicions. +1

Comment: Thanks for the intervention. You've thrown some very nasty terms at me :), so I guess I understood about 50% of what you've written. But I think I at least got the essential: I really need either a VPS or a dedicated server which I can run socket.io in conjunction with node.js on.